# Is the Greek myth about the early-flowering crocus, hyacinths and daffodils an authentic version of native Indo-European beliefs?

Tags: greek, european-folklore

Is the Greek mythology about the early-flowering crocus, hyacinths and daffodils unchanged and authentically / natively Indo-European ?
Like all early bloomers, daffodils are a symbol of rebirth, the victory of life over death (represented by winter) and they also had this meaning in pre-Christian Indo-European mythology :

https://www.floraqueen.com/blog/daffodils-the-march-birth-flower-that-announces-the-return-of-beautiful-sunny-days

The mythology known today around these plants no longer contains any aspect of rebirth and is heavily burdened with violence.

- Daffodils : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissus_in_culture
- Hyacinth : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyacinth_(mythology)
- Crocos : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crocus_(mythology)

Given that early-flowering plants are a very intuitive symbol of rebirth and the victory of life over death, can today's known Greek mythology be considered authentic and unchanged ?

Comment: Are you asking if the Greek myth is unchanged from its Indo-European precursor? Almost surely not and there's no way to definitively answer this. We just don't have actual records and comparative studies don't give you the level of details you'll need for such precision.

Comment: @Semaphore I think you are correct, a defining characteristic of most mythological stories is that they evolve in time, while some aspects might be inherited from an earlier Indo-European myth, the lack of concrete data and sources significantly impairs our ability to be sure. Greek mythology definitely changed over time and borrowed and inherited a lot from other mythologies. I have no time these days for an answer but this might steer someone in the right direction.